# Why there is no operator for time in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, operators

Is there one central reason why there is no "Time" operator in QM?

I know this question has been asked before, but I thought I would try to stimulate some fresh thinking.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34243/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6584/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You are rather unlikely to find any fresh thinking. This is very old question (by the standards of modern physics).