# Time evolution in Quantum Mechanics abstract state space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hilbert-space, time-evolution

As I've learned the first postulate from Quantum Mechanics can be stated as follows:

> The states of a quantum system are described by vectors in a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

The book then emphasises that $\mathcal{H}$ is not necessarily $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some $n$, i.e. it is not necessarily the space of wave functions. The author says an element $\left|\psi\right\rangle\in \mathcal{H}$ instead of being a wave function is an abstract object containing all the information about the system in that state.

In that setting, as I understood, wave functions appear as one possible representation of the states of the system in the case where we are dealing with a particle without spin. In that case, for each ket $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ one associates a function $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and one has $\left\langle x\right|$ being defined by

$$\left \langle x |\psi\right\rangle=\psi(x)$$

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, the evolution of a wave function is simply given by the Schroedinger equation. In other words, the evolution $t\mapsto \Psi(\cdot ,t)$ with $\Psi(\cdot, t)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is given by

$$-i\hbar \dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}(x,t)=\hat{H}\Psi(x,t)$$

where $\hat{H} : L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Hamiltonian operator for the particle.

But what about the general case? If $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hilbert space for a certain quantum system and if we have one initial state $\left|\psi_0\right\rangle$ given, what is the time evolution in this case? In my opinion it can't be the Schrodinger equation as is, because the kets $\left|\psi\right\rangle\in \mathcal{H}$ are not functions.

Considering this, how does one deals with the time evolution of general quantum systems in this abstract state space formalism?

Comment: Short answer is this:  $|\psi(t)\rangle$ is a *ket valued function of time* which associates a ket (state vector) with every value of $t$.  The abstract Schrodinger equation is equivalent to $$|\psi(t + dt)\rangle = |\psi(t)\rangle - \frac{i}{\hbar}H|\psi(t)\rangle dt$$

Answer (score 3):

The Schrödinger equation is not limited to any particular kind of Hilbert space. There's no problem with abstract kets.

Given a space of states $\mathcal{H}$, a *Schrödinger (or time-dependent) state* is given by a (smooth) map
$$ \lvert\psi(\dot{})\rangle : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{H}, t \mapsto \lvert \psi(t) \rangle$$
so the Schrödinger state $\lvert\psi(\dot{})\rangle$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{H})$ and time evolution is given by it fulfilling the Schrödinger equation
$$ \mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_t\lvert\psi(t)\rangle = H\lvert\psi(t)\rangle$$
where it has to be understood that the $\partial_t$ acts on the function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{H}$ (i.e. $\partial_t\lvert\psi(t)\rangle$ is the *derivative* of $\lvert\psi(\dot{})\rangle$ evaluated at $t$) and the $H$ acts on its *value* in $\mathcal{H}$ at the time $t$.

It is important to realize that the time derivative acts on *functions into the space of states* and is not an operator on the space of states itself, see also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/199846/50583).

Answer (score 2):

Who says kets are not functions? A ket can be a function of time: $|\psi(t)\rangle$. Since they are elements of a vector space (with a complete inner product), you can define their derivative:

$$\frac{d|\psi\rangle}{dt} =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|\psi(t+h)\rangle-|\psi(t)\rangle}{h}$$

And given a Hamiltonian $H : \mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$, which is a linear operator on the Hilbert space (and may even be a function of time itself), Schrödinger's equation reads:

$$i\hbar \frac{d|\psi(t)\rangle}{dt} = H |\psi(t)\rangle$$