# Hamiltonian in commutator contradiction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time, hamiltonian, commutator

Consider the following: 
$$[ \hat H, \hat x]=\left[-\frac{\hbar^2 \hat p^2}{2m}+V,\hat x\right]\ne0 \text{ in general}$$
But 
$$[ \hat H, \hat x]=\left[i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial t},\hat x\right]=0 $$
Why are these not in contradiction?

Comment: Because the time derivative is not an operator on the space of states, so your second equation is meaningless, see e.g. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199844/50583)

Comment: @ACuriousMind are you basically saying that states are a function of position only and the time part just describes the evolution of that position, as such to have an operator that takes a time derivative would be operating on something that we should consider to be 'fixed'?

Comment: @Joseph In addition to ACuriousMind's link you might find this helpful too, in particular Qmechanic's answer as to why $\hat H\neq i\hbar \partial _t$. http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/17479/

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for your links, these pretty much answer my question and I think this one should be closed as a duplicate of either of them. I have added another question on a similar topic, using the ideas in these links, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219669/.

Comment: @AngusTheMan see my comment above.