# Why is the wave function an element of the function space?

Tags: wavefunction, hilbert-space

The general wave function is of the form

$$\Psi \left ( x,y,z,t \right )=\psi \left ( x,y,z \right )T\left ( t \right )$$

Solving via separation of variables and finding the product solutions yields, for a particle in one dimension,

$$\Psi \left ( x,t \right ) = \psi\left ( x \right )e^{-i\omega t}=Ae^{i\left ( kx-\omega t \right )}+Be^{-i\left ( kx+\omega t \right )} $$\par$$
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

It is obvious that wave function obeys the superposition principle.

I have the mathematical methods for understanding Hilbert space(sequence space and function space) equivalent to an undergraduate level, in principle. 
Give or take, due memory loss.

Anyone kind enough to give an explanation?

Edit: Also open to explanation from a group theory approach.

Comment: The wave-function in general is square integrable so it belongs to $L^2$ or the hilbert space.

Comment: Does this follows from the normalisation of the probability density (modulus squared of probability amplitude)?
Equals to one(finite), on the infinite plane.
@Vishwaas

Comment: Yes, though there are other conditions required for a function to satisfy for it to belong in $L^2$, square integrability is one of them, see [Hilbert Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), may be an expert can give further insight on this

Comment: @Vishwaas
Yes. I understand the other condition is 'measurable' (equal 'almost' everywhere) but that would have to wait until my topology class of my math major in my final year next year.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe the answers to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219669/50583 are helpful to you.

Comment: Side note: the momentum and position "eigenstates" (you calculate a momentum eigenstate), are not proper states, they cannot be normalized and do not belong to the Hilbert space of states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write ***is not*** the general wavefunction. The wavefunction is a solution of the Schrödinger equation (Cauchy problem); and the Schrödinger equation has the form
$$i\partial_t u(t,x)=H(x,\nabla_x)u(t,x)\; ;$$
where $H(x,\partial_x)$ is a linear partial(or pseudo)-differential operator. This is a simple case of linear evolution PDE; and as for all PDEs, they make sense when considered on a certain function (or distribution) space.

Now, a natural question is: which space is the most suited one for quantum mechanics? Since we want the wavefunction to have meaning as a probability distribution when its modulus is squared, a natural candidate is the space of square integrable functions (this guarantees that the total probability is finite). However, it may as well be just a subset of it.

In my opinion, the "definitive" answer comes from changing point of view, and by considering quantum observables as a non-commutative algebra. This point of view is quite natural: the fundamental object in quantum physics are the observables, and we can see experimentally that in general they do not commute, take only real values, we can sum them etc... Summing up their properties, it is easy to see that they constitute the elements $\{A_i,i\in I\}$ of an involutive ($C^*$) algebra with involution $*$ such that $(\forall i\in I)A_i^*=A_i$.

Now the mathematical key point is that:

> Any $C^*$ algebra is isomorphic to an algebra of bounded linear operators on some Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$.

And any normalized vector (wavefunction) $f\in\mathscr{H}$ induces a state (non-commutative probability) for the observables considering the functional
$$\langle f,\,(\cdot)\, f\rangle_{\mathscr{H}} $$
acting on the operators. There are more general states that are not induced by wavefunctions, but ***any (normalized) wavefunction induces a quantum mechanical state***. This is why the wavefunctions have to be in the Hilbert space; and since every irreducible representation of the algebra of canonical commutation relations of QM (roughly speaking the Heisenberg group) is unitarily equivalent to the representation on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it is natural in QM to consider square integrable normalized wavefunctions $\psi$ as "states" (more precisely, they induce a quantum state). I don't want to enter into further details, however the natural concept of unitary evolution in this algebraic setting  translates obviously to the fact that the wavefunctions have to obey the Schrödinger equation, with a self-adjoint generator of the dynamics $H(x,\nabla_x)$.