# Why isn't the time dependent Schrödinger equation in the momentum basis simply the time independent one?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, time-evolution

If $-i \frac{ \partial}{\partial x}$ becomes $p$ in the momentum basis, I would expect the energy to be the same:

$$i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \to E$$

So the time dependent Schrödinger equation becomes:

$$E\psi=H\psi$$

But I believe the $E$ is variable unlike the time independent one which is constant. Is this the case?

Comment: The time derivative is not an operator on the Hilbert space.

Comment: Oh okay. If we try to incorporate special relativity, is that what happens to some extent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't the time-derivative considered an operator in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199844/)

Comment: Not really that wasn't my problem.

Comment: Then please clarify what your question actually is, i.e. edit the question accordingly...