# Heisenberg formalism of QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Has anyone tried to develop relativistic quantum theory along the lines of the Heisenberg picture and what's so difficult about promoting time to an operator??

Comment: There *is* a Heisenberg formalism of QFT. But in QFT, we don't promote the coordinates, we promote the fields, so the second part of your question doesn't mesh well with the first.

Comment: I am reading Srednicki and that's how he defines a Heisenberg formalism- as promoting time to an operator

Comment: I've never read Srednicki, but that's not what the [Heisenberg picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) is.

Comment: Ok maybe i misinterpreted, but what's so hard about promoting time as an operator "The many times are the problem; any monotonic
function of τ is just as good a candidate as τ itself for the proper time, and
this infinite redundancy of descriptions must be understood and accounted
for" trying to explain that in layman's terms might help!!

Comment: Why time is not a good operator has been already discussed [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34243/), [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83701/), [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6584/) and possibly at a hundred other questions, too.

Comment: @ACuriousMind making use of the covariant quantization, time and space are treated in exactly the same way ...

Comment: @Dilaton: If I understand covariant quantization ala DeDonder/Weyl correctly, the parameters of the background manifold (of which time is then one), do not become operators in that approach either, but only the fields on the background manifold. So time and space are treated equally, but neither becomes an operator.