# Snyder spacetime: are position and time true (quantum) operators there?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, operators, time, non-commutative-theory

Snyder spacetime is generally considered one of the first models of non-commutative and quantum spacetime. There is no time operator in Quantum Mechanics. Is  time in quantized Snyder space a true operator?

Answer (score 1):

1. One can in principle rewrite a $\color{red}{\text{non-commutative}}$ spacetime 
   $$ \{ x^{\mu},x^{\nu}\}_{PB} ~=~\color{red}{\theta^{\mu\nu}}, \qquad 
   \{x^{\mu},p_{\nu}\}_{PB}~=~\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}, \qquad 
   \{p_{\mu},p_{\nu}\}_{PB}~=~0 , \qquad \mu,\nu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\}, $$
   as a usual commutative spacetime
   $$ \{ X^{\mu},X^{\nu}\}_{PB} ~=~0, \qquad 
   \{X^{\mu},P_{\nu}\}_{PB}~=~\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}, \qquad 
   \{P_{\mu},P_{\nu}\}_{PB}~=~0 , \qquad \mu,\nu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\},$$
   by going to [Darboux coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem). For constant $\theta^{\mu\nu}$, a possible transformation is
   $$ X^{\mu}~=~x^{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\theta^{\mu\nu}p_{\nu}, \qquad  P_{\mu}~=~p_{\mu}, \qquad \mu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\}. $$
2. Because of point 1 the question

   > Is time an operator/observable $\hat{X}^0$ or merely a parameter $X^0$ in quantum theories?

   remains more or less the same for commutative and $\color{red}{\text{non-commutative}}$ spacetimes, cf. Pauli's theorem and e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220697/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.