# Momentum operator in spacelike metric convention

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions

What are the underlying principles for choosing signs for the momentum operators in QM/QFT?

Let's say, for the $(+,-,-,-)$ metric convention we have $\partial^\mu = (+\partial_0,-\nabla)$. Why not $\partial^\mu = (-\partial_0,+\nabla)$?
Is it due to the Canonical Commutation Relations $[p^\mu,x^\nu]=ig^{\mu\nu}$?

How then does one decide on the momentum operator components in $(-,+,+,+)$ metric?
Should we fix CCR as $[p^\mu,x^\nu]=-ig^{\mu\nu}$ or $[p^\mu,x^\nu]=+ig^{\mu\nu}$?

Is there any cheatsheet (paper/textbook) with sign conventions for momentum operators, EM field tensor, etc?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, note that
   $$ \partial_{\mu}~:=~\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} , \qquad \mu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\},\tag{A}$$
   and $$ \partial^{\mu}~:=~g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}, \qquad \mu~\in~\{0,1,2,3\}.\tag{B}$$
   More generally, we use [the metric to raise and lower indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism). Eq. (B) explains OP's first eq.
2. The standard [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) reads
   $$ [\hat{x}^j,\hat{p}_k]~=~i\hbar\delta^j_k \mathbb{1}, \qquad j,k~\in~\{1,2,3\}. \tag{C}$$
   In the Schrödinger representation
   $$\hat{x}^j~=~x^j, \qquad \hat{p}_j~=~\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}, \qquad j~\in~\{1,2,3\}. \tag{D}$$
   OP's CCR and momentum operator should agree with eqs. (C) & (D).
3. Note that time $x^0$ is a *parameter* not an operator in quantum mechanics, so that
   $$ [x^0,\hat{p}_0]~=~0, \tag{E}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220697/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17477/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about time. But the question remains. What is the principle for choosing the momentum operator components in arbitrary metric (spacelike, in my case)?

Comment: I updated the answer.