# The origin and current status of the equation $\boldsymbol {Et}-\boldsymbol {tE}=\frac{h}{2\pi i}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, history

Heisenberg already in 1927 quotes this equation as a "known equation".<sup>[1]</sup>

I would like to know that what was the original conception behind this equation, and what is its current status. According to our current knowledge, does it have any correct meaning?

---

<sub>[1] Über den anschaulichen Inhalt der quantentheoretischen Kinematik und Mechanik, Zeits. f. Phys. 43 172 1927. (p.8. in [pdf in English](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19840008978.pdf)),</sub>

Comment: Are you asking how Heisenberg derived the equation back in the 1920s, or are you asking how the equation is derived now? The former would be better asked on the [History of Science Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As far as I know, this equation now isn't regarded valid because there is no bounded self-adjount operator for this $\boldsymbol t$. So I'm interested now in the history. Thank y you for the link, I didn't know that.

Comment: There is an excellent summary of the current approach to the energy time uncertainty equation in [What is Δt in the time-energy uncertainty principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of physics and would be better asked on the [History of Science Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks again, for your second link too. I'm seriously considering to move to the History of Science. However, I don't really understand that what is the role of the 'history' tag here if not for asking historycal questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as partly because it was crossposted.

Comment: I made an attempt to make this post ontopic. Could you please check it?

Comment: Great! Here is voted to offtopc but got 19 views and a +1, whille on the History SE got 2 views and a -1. What should I do?

Comment: Seems questionable to me that this is considered offtopic for physics SE. The derivation and origin of the inequality is a physical result and without math it's not properly explainable; history is not the right place for it. Also, the answer to the Q is nontrivial, and that is especially important because of how widely the relation is used without knowing how to prove it. If it is already answered in another post, that is another story, but off-topic it is not. Sometimes making phys SE "clean" from a moderator POV reduces its helpfulness to the community

Comment: @mma there is a good source to read a summary of the time-energy uncertainty relation today. That is Muga's book "Time in Quantum Mechanics", a really nice book dealing with issues related to $t$ in QM. The 3rd chapter is a summary of the understanding of the uncertainty relation. If you want more, you can also try "Quantum Theory and Measurement" by Wheeler, Zurek.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220697/2451 and links therein.